# nodejs express close server when request is done

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a test script for my module and I need to be able to close my server when my request is done. The following code works but I can see that app.close() was dropped from express 3. What's the best way to do it now?

```
var testCase = require('nodeunit').testCase;
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();
var srv = app.listen();
....

request({
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: { id: 'second request'},
    url: 'http://' + target
  }, function(err, res, body) {

    console.info("closing server");
    app.close();
    test.done();
  });
});
```

Thanks,
Li

p.s. test.done() must be called after closing the server, otherwise the test will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express applications used to inherit from `http.Server`, which they no longer do, and that's where the `close` method came from. Instead, call `close()` on your `srv` instance. You may commonly see this code written as:

```
var app = express.createServer();
var srv = require('http').createServer(app);
srv.listen(port);
```

According to [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen) for `app.listen()`:

> Bind and listen for connections on the given host and port, this method is identical to node's `http.Server#listen()`.

Comment: I tried to run this with express 2.5 and it gives me the following error: throw new Error('addListener only takes instances of Function'); I guess "app" is not an instance of a Function in express 2.5... Any idea how to manipulate the code so it will work? (I want the code to run on express 2.5 and higher versions)

Comment: They have two different interfaces, so you'd need to write two versions of the code. I suppose you could check `typeof app` to see if it's a function or not.

Comment: so if it's a function I should use the new code, and if not I should use the old code with the app.close()?

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. Since even in Express 3, `app.listen()` returns a Server, it would take care of both instances.

Comment: Note that `server.close()` will only close the response is sent and if the client is not keeping a persistent HTTP connection. Refer to https://dev.to/gajus/how-to-terminate-a-http-server-in-node-js-ofk