# How to properly close Node.js Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

I need to close server after getting callback from `/auth/github/callback`
url. With usual **[HTTP API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html)** closing
server is currently supporting with [`server.close([callback])`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html)
API function, but with node-express server i’m getting `TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'close'`
error. And I don't know how to find information to solve this problem.
**How should I close express server?**

NodeJS configuration notes:

```
$ node --version
v0.8.17
$ npm --version
1.2.0
$ npm view express version
3.0.6
```

Actual application code:

```
var app = express();

// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
    // … configuration
});

app.get(
    '/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');

        setTimeout(function () {
            app.close();
            // TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'close'
        }, 3000)
    }
);

app.listen('http://localhost:5000/');
```

Also, I have found [‘nodejs express close…’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293257/nodejs-express-close-server-when-request-is-done?rq=1) but I don't sure if I can use it with code I have: `var app = express();`.

Comment: I'm starting a express into a unit test. In this scope, close() does not stop the server

Comment: @JRichardsz maybe API had changed in the last 8 years

Comment: @JRichardsz See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739334/1057730

Comment: I think the problem is in due to mocha. I will prepare a minimal runnable sample. My workaround is process.exit(0)

Comment: @JRichardsz it is not mocha. process.exit(0) to workaround, is what axe is to headache.

Comment: What i wanted to say is that in my case I'm using a express insise of mocha test. In this particular scenario, close() don't works. Just process.exit(0) works :(

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`app.listen()` returns `http.Server`. You should invoke `close()` on that instance and not on `app` instance.

Ex.

```
app.get(
    '/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');

        setTimeout(function () {
            server.close();
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^
        }, 3000)
    }
);

var server = app.listen('http://localhost:5000/');
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can inspect sources: `/node_modules/express/lib/application.js`

Comment: Strange, it is not closing if I access some route.

Comment: @Uday, I also experienced this.  I found out that my browser had an HTTP1.1 persistant connection open, so when I pressed F5 it appeared as though the server didn't close.  If you try a different browser you will see the server socket is not running.

Comment: That was my mistake, I was calling close on `app` instead of `server`. Saved my day. Many thanks 

Comment: why the Timeout?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira it seems that Vladimir simply followed the example OP gave where they close after 3 seconds

Answer (score 64):

In express v3 they removed this function.

You can still achieve the same by assigning the result of `app.listen()` function and apply close on it:

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
server.close((err) => {
  console.log('server closed')
  process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
})
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1366

Comment: Use something like https://github.com/gajus/http-terminator to ensure termination of the server in case there are persistent connections or requests not producing a response.

Comment: short and simple

Answer (score 14):

If any error occurs in your express app then you must have to close the server and you can do that like below-

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

If any error occurs then our application will get a signal named `SIGTERM`. You can read more SIGTERM here - https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.info('SIGTERM signal received.');
  console.log('Closing http server.');
  server.close((err) => {
    console.log('Http server closed.');
    process.exit(err ? 1 : 0);
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry, its not relevant. Question is about manual server shutdown and not about error handling

Comment: are you sure `server.close` has a callback? I don't see it in the documentation

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira - yup, it's [certainly there](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback)

Comment: @OlegValter thanks but I read that expressJs server does not inherit anymore from nodejs http-server

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira last time I checked, `app.listen` call still does: "The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object and (for HTTP) is a convenience method for the following"

Answer (score 4):

I have answered a variation of "how to terminate a HTTP server" many times on different [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) support channels. Unfortunately, I couldn't recommend any of the existing libraries because they are [lacking](https://github.com/gajus/http-terminator#alternative-libraries) in one or another way. I have since put together a package that (I believe) is handling all the cases expected of graceful express.js HTTP(S) server termination.

https://github.com/gajus/http-terminator

The main benefit of [http-terminator](https://github.com/gajus/http-terminator) is that:

- it does not monkey-patch Node.js API
- it immediately destroys all sockets without an attached HTTP request
- it allows graceful timeout to sockets with ongoing HTTP requests
- it properly handles HTTPS connections
- it informs connections using keep-alive that server is shutting down by setting a connection: close header
- it does not terminate the Node.js process

Comment: It remains a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but now Node **v18.2.0** [introduced](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#servercloseallconnections) `server.closeAllConnections()`. It should be noted that `server.close` never runs its callback when the browser sends the request `Connection: keep-alive`, because `server.close` only stops the server from accepting new connections, it does not close old connections.

Before Node v18.2.0 I tackled this problem by waiting 5 seconds for the server to shutdown, after which it would force exit.

This code encompasses both situations

```js
process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown)
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown)

function gracefulShutdown (signal) {
  if (signal) console.log(`\nReceived signal ${signal}`)
  console.log('Gracefully closing http server')

  try {
    server.close(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('There was an error', err.message)
        process.exit(1)
      } else {
        console.log('http server closed successfully. Exiting!')
        process.exit(0)
      }
    })

    // closeAllConnections() is only available from Node v18.02
    if (server.closeAllConnections) server.closeAllConnections()
    else setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 5000)

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('There was an error', err.message)
    setTimeout(() => process.exit(1), 500)
  }
}
```

Comment: i think closeAllConnections() has to be called AFTER calling close().

Comment: @Welcor why do you say that? Shouldn't we close connections before closing the server?

Comment: close() stops accepting new connections but will keep all existing connections. As long as connections exists it will not close. I think, when you call closeAllConnections() before close() there is a possibility that a connection is created between closeAll..() and close(). Then close() will not close until this connection closes itself.

Comment: @Welcor I don't think so, if you call `close` without previously calling `closeAllConnections`, if you have a pending connection (for example waiting for a response), `server` will never trigger its callback. That's why before node 18  you have to force exit after a timeout.

Comment: the pending connection will be closed by closeAllConnections() after the close(). this then triggers the close() callback. timeline: close() -> closeAllConnections() -> close() callback called.

Answer (score 2):

calling `server.close` does the job

```js
server.close((err) => {
  console.log('server closed')
  process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
})
```

also it is good to listen for system(user) signals and shutdown gracefully on them too, for that you should listen on both `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(port);
console.log(`listening on port:${port}`);
for (let signal of ["SIGTERM", "SIGINT"])
    process.on(signal, () => {
        console.info(`${signal} signal received.`);
        console.log("Closing http server.");
        server.close((err) => {
            console.log("Http server closed.");
            process.exit(err ? 1 : 0);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers call `process.exit()`, I don't think this is a good idea. You probably need to perform some teardown, also it's simply not needed.

```
const server = app.listen(port);

server.on('close', () => {
  // Perform some teardown, for example with Knex.js: knex.destroy()
});

// FYI Docker "stop" sends SIGTERM
// If SIGTERM is not catched, Docker is forced to kill the container after ~10s
// and this provokes an exit code 137 instead of 0 (success)
process.on('SIGTERM', () => server.close());
```

Check Express.js 4.x documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/healthcheck-graceful-shutdown.html#graceful-shutdown

Comment: I think you missed the 1st sentence in the question: "I need to close server after getting callback from /auth/github/callback url."