# mocha 'after' fails saying it can't find 'app'

Tags: express, mocha.js

Ok, my mocha tests will pass if I comment out the 'before' and 'after' methods.  I am sure that both of my errors are related to each other.

The 'after' method fails stating app.close isn't a function.  The 'before' method fails saying it cant find 'app' on my line 7 (clearing server cache).

I am completely out of options or ideas.  I would like to be able to start and stop my server at my command.  This is the first time that I have attempted to include any type of 'before/after' methods to my mocha testing.  working code below, but with my failing portion commented out.  Any suggestions??

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../../server');

describe('server', function() {
    before(function () {
        //var app = require('../../server')();
        //delete require.cache[require.resolve('app')];
    });
    after(function () {
        //app.close();
    });
    describe('basic comms', function() {
        it('responds to root route', function testSlash(done) {
            request(app)
                .get('/')
                .expect('Content-type', /json/)
                //.expect(res.message).to.equal('Hello World!')
                .expect(200, done);
        });
        it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
            //console.log('testing 404 response');
            request(app)
                .get('/foo/bar')
                .expect(404, done);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `before` you require your app in a different way than in line 2. Why would you not use already required app?

Example:

```
before(function () {
    // here you can use app from line 2
});
```

Regarding `app.close`, where did you find this function?

Check Express docs:
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app

To close express server, you can use this approach:

[how to properly close node-express server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515954/how-to-properly-close-node-express-server)

Comment: Thank you @Andrei.  I took your suggestion with that last link and used it. As far as leaving line 2 in there to ref my server, I did that so that I could activate it or comment it out when I needed to, to test that my 'it' still worked without anything being in my 'before' or 'after'.  Now that your suggestion proved AWESOME, I have permanently moved that line to my 'before'.  Thank you.