# server.close is not a function

Tags: express, jestjs, supertest

I have a jest supertest setup for my testing , I am trying to close server after tests are done but it is throwing error, it is saying server.close() is not a function. what is wrong here? is it issue with express or jest or supertest I am not able to figure it out  I am new to testing please help me.

server.js file:

```js
const next = require("next");
const express = require("express");
const winston = require("winston");
const config = require("config");
const passport = require("passport");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const path = require("path");
var cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

var app = express();

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({dev});
const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
const handleRequest = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  require("./server/startup/cors")(app);
  require("./server/startup/db")();

  app.use(cookieParser("ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch"));
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      name: "MyAppName",
      keys: ["very secret key"],
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
    })
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(flash());

  require("./server/services/passport")(passport);

  require("./server/startup/logging")();
  require("./server/startup/routes")(app);
  require("./server/startup/prod")(app);

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handleRequest(req, res);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`));

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my test file:

```js
const request = require("supertest");

const {User} = require("./../../server/models/user");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let server;

beforeEach(() => {
  server = require("./../../server");
});
afterEach(async () => {
  await server.close();
});

describe("POST /api/signup", () => {
  it("should signin successfully", () => {});
});
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError: server.close is not a function

       9 | beforeEach(() => { server = require('./../../server'); });
      10 |   afterEach(async () => {    > 11 |     await server.close();
         |                  ^
      12 |
      13 |   });
```

what is happening here? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to properly close node-express server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515954/how-to-properly-close-node-express-server)

Answer (score 13):

In order to close the server, you must obtain the instance that is returned from the `listen` function. In your example, it appears that you call that function here:

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`));
```

So, you would need to get the instance returned and close that. E.g.

```
let appServer = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`));
...
appServer.close()
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, I followed the suggestion but I still get the error

Answer (score 8):

At the end of your index.js, you want to export the listener, not app, so...

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`));
module.exports = app;
```

becomes...

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`));
module.exports = server;
```

Should work from there.