# Can't stop express server in after function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing

I have Node tests with this `before` function:

```
before((done) => {
  app.startServer()
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
  });
});
```

I'm now trying to write an `after` function which will stop the server.

I had hoped this could be:

```
after(() => {
  app.stopServer(apiAddress)
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    })
});
```

but that doesn't work.

These are my `express.js` functions:

```
function startServer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      log.info(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

function stopServer(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //const server = app.listen(url);
    app.close(url, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      log.info(`Server closed on ${url}`);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

How do I stop my `express` server in an after function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515954/how-to-properly-close-node-express-server) stack overflow question and looking at [express](http://expressjs.com/) documentation.

[app.listen](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen_path_callback)

> The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object and (for HTTP)
>   is a convenience method for the following:

---

The `close` method you are calling is the [Http.close](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) method which is defined like :

```
server.close([callback])
```

So your function should look like :

```
function stopServer(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.close((err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

      log.info(`Server closed on ${url}`);

      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Also, you have to know that the `close` function will hang until all connections are closed.

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately)

---

---

NOTE :

You can use `Util.promisify` to simplify the syntax

```
function startServer() {
  return Util.promisify(app.listen)(PORT);
}

function stopServer(url) {
  return Util.promisify(app.close)();
}

before((done) => {
  app.startServer()
    .then(() => done)
    .catch(done);
});

after(() => {
  app.stopServer()
    .then(() => done)
    .catch(done);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I placed that in a describe block. When the next describe block runs this error is thrown in the before function: `Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::1337`

Comment: I think that an old node.js is running, so the address is already taken. Kill the processes then it will work. You can identify the processes using `htop` or a command like `ps -aux | grep node`. Or `lsof -t -i:1337` so to kill it `kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:1337)`

Comment: I already tried `lsof -t -i:1337` with no joy. Is there some possible async issue between describe blocks?

Comment: I don't think so, before will execute first and then fail

Answer (score 1):

We use ‘supertest’ npm package for testing Express.js applications. Try that nice thing.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest