# How to close graphql-yoga server?

Tags: express, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

For express it is described in

[how to properly close node-express server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515954/how-to-properly-close-node-express-server)

but in documentation of yoga

https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga

there is not info about `close` method.

---

## UPDATE

Solution of @perdox solves my problem, correct answer is:

```
const gqlServer = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const server = gqlServer.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'));
(async function f() {
    (await server).close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQLYoga is a collection of tools and uses / wraps the express server.

See: https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga/blob/master/src/index.ts

So as you can see in the source code the GraphQLServer wraps the express server and the start method returns a HttpServer Promise. So you should be able to close the server by invoking the close method on the HttpServer:

```
const gqlServer = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
const server = gqlServer.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
server.close()
```