# close server from within router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodejs-server

I create an express app like this

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/close', async (_, res) => {
  res.status(200);
  res.end();
  app.close();
});

module.exports = app;
```

I instantiate it in another module

```
const myApp = require('./app.js');
myApp.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started server on ${port}`);
});
```

I want the server to shut itself down when it receives a post request to `/close`. At the moment, I just get a `app.close` is not a function error.

I know I can close a server externally like this

```
const server = myApp.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started server on ${port}`);
});
server.close();
```

but I want to close the server on a post request to `/close`, how can I do that?

Comment: Accepted answer here might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515954/how-to-properly-close-node-express-server

Comment: @ozgur it still uses the `server` instance which my app doesn't have access to

Comment: I get the idea now. Could it be done using events?

Comment: Have you considered using `worker_threads`?

Comment: @AdamAzad no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to your server object, try using

```
req.connection.server
```

from within your route handler.

[`.close()` makes the server stop](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback) [listening](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listening) for new connections. Already-established connections are not affected. The server object emits a `'close'` event when all open connections have disconnected.

`process.exit()` stops your whole nodejs app.

So, this code might do what you want.

```
app.post('/close', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200)
  res.end()
  const server = req.connection.server
  if (server.listening) {
    server.addEventListener('close', ev => {
      console.log('server closed. See ya later alligator.')
      process.exit(0)
    })
    console.log('closing server')
    server.close()
  }
});
```

If you need to get the server object from your app object (if getting it from your req object isn't good enough), you could put in a little middleware function like this.

```
app.use( function adornApp( req, res, next ) {
  req.app.locals.server = req.connection.server
  next()
} )
```

Then you'll be able to get your server from `app.locals.server` once your middleware is first invoked.

Comment: I experimented with this. It takes 2-3 calls to `close` to actually terminate the server.

Comment: Right. `.close()` makes the server stop listening. Already-established connections are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [http-terminator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-terminator) package to close your server. The following should do the trick. The reason we use the `http-terminator` is because the server won't close if it is visited via a route.

```
const { createHttpTerminator } = require("http-terminator");
const { initApp, app } = require("./app.js");

const PORT = 3000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Started server on ${PORT}`);
});

const httpTerminator = createHttpTerminator({ server });

initApp(httpTerminator);
```

Inside the module:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const initApp = (httpTerminator) => {
  app.get("/close", async (_, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "we closed" });
    await httpTerminator.terminate();
  });
};

module.exports = { initApp, app };
```

Comment: This still requires the httpServer instance, which my router doesn't have access to

Comment: @minseong you could add a wrapper function inside your module and export that as well. Then add all routes that use the `httpTerminator` instance inside the function. See code snippet

Comment: @Reyno, great approach, but I think OP wants to close the server without having to refactor his code: access the server instance.